# function is being invoked even though it's not being called in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I came across this problem where I'm not calling the function f(), yet the object 'obj' is invoked even though we also aren't doing anything with 'obj'.  The value of x to 11.
Does it invoke the function f() when attempting to set obj.g to a value?

```js
var x = 10;

function f () {
  console.log(x); //logs 10
  x = x + 1;
  console.log(x); //logs 11
  return x;
}


var obj = {
  func: f,
  g: f(),
};

console.log(x); // logs 11
```

Comment: "Does it invoke the function f() when attempting to set obj.g to a value?" Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `g: f()` you are actually invoking the function. Specifying `()` after a function without function body (`{..}`) will execute the function immediately. Just remove the parenthesis after the function name:

```js
var x = 10;

function f () {
  console.log(x); //logs 10
  x = x + 1;
  console.log(x); //logs 11
  return x;
}


var obj = {
  func: f,
  g: f,
};

console.log(x); // logs 10
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it invoke the function f() when attempting to set obj.g to a
>   value?

Yup!

`f` is invoked when assigning `obj.g`.

You're assigning `obj.g` to the return value of calling `f` with no arguments. To get the value, the function (`f`) has to be invoked.

---

`console.log(obj.g); // 11`